# Type Native Javascript Error class with declarations

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I want to type the native Class [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). The property `cause` in `Error` has the type `unknown` and I want it to be a enum I created myself.

The `Error` object look like this:

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
    cause: unkownwn;
}
```

I want to override cause using a declaration file, how can i do this?

Comment: interface CauseError extends Error {
    cause: 'CAUSE1' | 'Cause2';
}
 or
import {Error as BaseError} from "error"

interface  Error extends BaseError {
    cause: 'CAUSE1' | 'Cause2';
}

Comment: @Lapwood import from what?

Comment: From other file where the original interface Error are declared by the way you can also use a generic type interface CustomError<T> extends Error {
    cause: T;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the type of an existing property.

You can add a property:

```
interface A {
    newProperty: any;
}
```

But changing a type of existing one:

```
interface A {
    property: any;
}
```

Results in an error:

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable
> 'property' must be of type 'number', but here has type 'any'

You can of course have your own interface which extends an existing one. In that case, you can override a type only to a compatible type, for example:

```
interface A {
    x: string | number;
}

interface B extends A {
    x: number;
}
```